# How can I post files from my memory Into a website using php coding

Tags: php, html, http, post, httprequest

I wanna send a photo with a telegram bot into my telegram account using a PHP code. 
For this , I have to post my file and my telegram ID to this URL : `https://api.telegram.org/bot213276334:AAGwyAFdPgg1Wa6hifAfZfeSfgKs_fwS38w/sendPhoto`

I tried this Code :

```
<?php
$botToken="213276334:AAGwyAFdPgg1Wa6hifAfZfeSfgKs_fwS38w";
$website="https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;
?>
<form action="<?php echo $website.'/sendphoto' ?>" method="post" enctype ="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="text" name ="chat_id" value="MY_ID" />
     <input type="file" name="photo" />
     <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

It worked ; but I don't wanna choose my photo And my ID from within the script . I wanna put my id And my file's path in the text , And when i run the script , It upload them itself , And I don't choose them from Input Page .
Can you help me please?